# How to place text with mouseClick listener inside of cell of table?

Tags: java, gwt, cell, celltable

I need to place a text that has listener on it inside of cell of celltable. I also want to render a window after it was clicked. I am somehow failing to achieve this. Please note that I am new to gwt.

Comment: I've just started working on it, but hit the wall.

Comment: As @Dahaka said, code would help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by inserting [ClickableTextCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ClickableTextCell.html) in table. Clicking on this table triggers [ValueUpdater](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ValueUpdater.html).update(value) method. 
Inside update you can do what you want.